# How to easily find Apps Script project connected to Google Cloud system project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

Is there a simple way how to find Google Apps Script project which is connected to system cloud project inside system-gsuite/apps-script in Google Cloud Console?

And vice-versa? To find the cloud project which is connected to Google Apps Script?

Comment: In the old editor you can go to resources/cloud platform project to go project to cloud

Answer (score 0):

In Google document, these are the instructions on how to connect Apps Script project to Google Cloud Platform:

For the New Editor, this is what you need to do:
[image]

And for the Legacy Editor:

[image]

#### Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects